# Our being vs. the fact that

Tags: grammar

While editing a writing sample of mine, my boyfriend made the following correction:

> When we are more active online, **our being** solely distributed in the Greater Detroit area will be inconsequential.
>
> When we are more active online, **the fact that we are** solely distributed in the Greater Detroit area will be inconsequential.

I've always been taught to avoid the "the fact that" construction. Is "our being" grammatically incorrect here?

Comment: What was *his* rationale for making the change?

Comment: One should avoid _the fact that_ **unless** one is vouching for a fact. But that's the situation here. Using a POSS-_ing_ gerund like _our being_ is not ungrammatical, but it is fancy, and it feels like a weak evasion, because it isn't as direct about the facts.

Comment: @Janel:  "Our being" is acceptable.  In your future writing endeavors, you might think about using the gerund-possessive construction when it is clearly the subject of your sentence.  Examples:  "Our loud talking kept our roommate awake at night"; or "My winning the race really irked him"; or "Just tell me when my snoring interrupts your sleep"; and so on.

Comment: I agree. Your "One should avoid "the fact that" is apt, as is the "exception" you mention. Lately, I've been hearing the wordy "on account of the fact that" a little too much, when a simple "because" would do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

*Our being* feels awkward and unprofessional, to me. This is a situation in which it would be fine to use *the fact that*, but you could also rearrange the sentence to avoid it and to be more specific. For example:

> We are solely distributed in the Greater Detroit area, but that will no longer be a problem when we are more active online.
>
> When we are more active online, it will no longer matter that we are distributed only in the Greater Detroit area.

Personally, I think your original construction using *the fact that* is fine, but rearranging a sentence to avoid using a phrase you don't like is always a good option!

Comment: Personally, I see nothing either 'awkward' nor 'unprofessional' in using 'our being'. It seems to me fairly elegant. I would, however, think hard before implying that being in the Detroit area is currently 'problematic' (which is implied by using 'will no longer be a problem'), depending who is the intended audience for this statement.